# Kinect 2.0 polling frames

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, kinect

I'm working on a c# .net project using a Kinect device and the official sdk 2.0. 
Right now I'm processing the frames via events but I'd like to try it via polling method
I've read about it in the documentation of the 1.0 version of the sdk but I've found nothing specific about the 2.0 version
Has Microsoft dropped support for polling frames or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is restricted to Kinect SDK 1.5 to 1.8
Check - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973076.aspx

For kinect SDK 2.0 you should use MultiSourceFrameReady
Check - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.multisourceframereader.aspx

And - http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look